# Hazelcast IMDG vs Hazelcast Jet

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I'm using Hazelcast IMDG in my application.

I heard that Hazelcast Jet provides fast data processing than Hazelcast IMDG.

If Yes.

Is Hazelcast Jet is open source?

Hazelcast Jet provides all the functionality which is available  Hazelcast IMDG?

Comment: Jet is now part of hazelcast core, meaning you get both with the same dependency. In particular you can't have a jet instance without a hazelcast instance. Jet runs on top of the IMDG it's not an either/or.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hazelcast Jet is open source?

> Yes, it is [open source](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet).

[Hazelcast jet](https://hazelcast.com/products/jet/) is build on top of Hazelcast IMDG.

If you want to do stream processing or batch processing in real time you should go with jet.
In case you need shared(Distributed) cache go with [Hazelcast IMDG](https://hazelcast.org/imdg/).

Comment: And if I’m using Hazelcast IMDG as a shared (distributed) Cache, and I wish to stream data from that cache (to be processed elsewhere, so I can’t use the IMDG EntryProcessor architecture) without incurring OutOfMemoryError-related issues?

Comment: Instead of running Jet jobs and IMDG caching services in one cluster, you can start a new Jet cluster that connects to the current IMDG cluster and streams the data out, see the how-to: https://jet-start.sh/docs/how-tos/stream-imap 

Just use Sources.remoteMapJournal() instead of Sources.mapJournal. 

This architecture isolates IMDG and Jet completely.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's [open-source](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet). You can use all of the functionality of Hazelcast from Jet, using `JetInstance.getHazelcastInstance()`.